# Chrome doesn't always jump to #top while Firefox is doing fine

Tags: html, google-chrome

### Site description

I have a page where a list of 10 `div` are showing at once while 100 are in the source document. On the bottom is a button that - if clicked - hides these 10 `div` and shows the next 10 `div`. The button itself is a styled link with `href="#top"` where the id belongs to my `navbar` on top.

### Problem

If I use Chrome it doesn't jump to top every time I click on the button. Sometime it jumps and sometimes it just show the new divs without the jump to top.

### What works

If I use Firefox there's no problem.

### Question

How can I figure out where's the problem - I mean, could there be an error somewhere else in my code that leads to this behaviour (no jump to `#top`) - or is there an alternative way to tell the users browser to jump to top that I should or could use?

Comment: If I can make a suggestion: I would handle the scrolling to top logic in Javascript instead of with links to anchors. Have your scroll-to-top button/link call a Javascript function that just calls `window.scrollTo(0, 0);`

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel This way it works. Thanks!

Comment: Alright, I'll convert to an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using anchors and links to them (because your anchors might change positions, or work different between browsers), you should use Javascript, using the `window.scrollTo()` function:

### HTML

```
<button onclick="scrollToTop()">Go to Top</button>
```

### Javascript

```
function scrollToTop(){
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Note that `scrollTo()` takes two parameters; the top and left position to scroll to. Also `scrollTo()` is *not* animated, it will scroll instantly to the position that you set.